# Counting specific characters in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

Other questions have been asked concerning word count in text areas, but they are not duplicates of this question:

What I am trying to do is write a JavaScript/jQuery function is called on the user clicking on a button. The function takes the value of a textarea and checks all the characters that are in there. And then check whether two characters have the same amount of occurrences. In the function I need to use an if-else statement.

Example:
If the input has 3x `[` and 3x `]`: `if (a.length == b.length) {}` (`= true`)

If the input has 3x `[` and 2x `]`: `if (a.length == b.length) {}` (`= false`)

But I am not quite sure how I can count individual characters. I am guessing with some regex and a `match`, but the following does not seem to work:

```js
var a = str.match(/\[+ /g),
    b = str.match(/\[+ /g);

if (a.length == b.length) {
    //do something
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YSEv/). As you can see, the count is not correct.

Comment: Please check your regexp syntax, `a+ /g` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: You can not count occurrences with regular grammars, you need another approach.

Comment: try something like /a/g

Comment: Everything within regexp counts, drop the space after `+`, if you want to count `[`(s) without space after it/them.

Comment: @Teemu Silly mistake, thanks! But how come that when I have two `]` right after each other, the count is not correct? (i.e. the second `]` isn't counted). See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4YSEv/1/) fiddle.

Comment: `+` matches the preceding character one or more times, it concatenates the sequential matches to one. Just drop the `+` too. Please see also, how to create [regexps dynamically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: @Bram its working
var str = $("textarea").val(),
    a = str.match(/a/g),
    b = str.match(/b/g);

$("span#a").html(a.length);
$("span#b").html(b.length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
'a[b][ca[]de'.match(/\[/g).length;
```

**output:**

```
3
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str =  'What I am trying to do is write a JavaScript/jQuery function is called on the user clicking on a button. The function takes the value of a textarea and checks all the characters that are in there. And then check whether two characters have the same amount of occurrences. In the function I need to use an if-else statement.'

var matchFrequency = function(a,b, text) {
    return text.split(a).length == text.split(b).length
}
matchFrequency('a','a',str)
//true
matchFrequency('a','b',str)
//false
```

**Edit**

```
var str = 'Hello [ Here are ] some random [ characters ]] And I need to [ count [ and ]'
matchFrequency('[',']',str)
//output - true
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work to you?

```
var aOccurrences = str.split("a").length - 1,
    bOccurrences = str.split("b").length - 1;

if(aOccurrences === bOccurrences) {
   //doSomething
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/4YSEv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Make an array which is indexed with 'a' to 'z'.

For example:

```
var arr=[];
```

initialize the array with 0.
I am giving code snippet here, I guess you can convert it into Javascript

```
for(i=0; i<='z'-'a';i++) // 'z'-'a' means ASCII value of 'z' minus ASCII value of 'a'
arr[i] = 0;

string text_area = the text area from input

for(i =0; i<text_area.length ; i++) //text_area.length = length of your text area
if(text_area[i]>='a'&&text_area[i]<='z') // considering only lower case letters for now   
arr[text_area[i]-'a'] = arr[text_area[i]-'a'] + 1; //if a character is found,add 1 to count
```

We have our arr[] ready. Now if we want to check if number of character 'C1' is equal to number of character 'C2', we need to check like this

```
if(arr['C1'-'a']==arr['C2'-'a'])
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is only partially, since I don't know how to handle regex under javascript/JQuery.
I will write it in java.
If you match each occurence of a and b, you can compare both :

```
Pattern pa=Pattern.compile("a");
Matcher ma=pa.match(str);
Pattern pb=Pattern.compile("b");
Matcher mb=pb.match(str);
int counta=0;
int countb=0;
while(ma.find())
counta++;
while(mb.find())
countb++;
boolean result=counta==countb;
```

This is an idea of the structure. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really can't do anything with this answer. Java doesn't help me any further.

Comment: Can I ask *why* you thought it reasonable to post a (possible) solution to a problem in the wrong language? What help do you think this provides? I don't speak Java, so I'm similarly unable to do anything with this to make it applicable to the posted problem.

Comment: I have some experiences in java, C# and other languages, concerning Regex. Since the grammatic is different, but the functions are always the same, I assumed it could help to build an architecture, then replace the wrong name and grammatik witht the good one. It seems that I was wrong!